# minifcation of a if expression, gives unexpected output

Tags: javascript

using a javascript minifier [here](https://javascript-minifier.com/), if found

```
if ($(this).val()) {
    idCat = $(this).val();
}
```

gets transformed into this expression

```
$(this).val()&&(idCat=$(this).val());
```

What is the rationale behind this tranformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique called a "Short-Circuit Evaluation".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation

Comment: i was on this very same page, and didn't bother to look further down. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).val()&&(idCat=$(this).val());
```

works like an simple AND condition where

`$(this).val()` and `(idCat=$(this).val())` are two conditions.

if `$(this).val()` is 0 or something that is Boolean equivant of false like `Boolean ("")` (i.e. val() returns an empty string) or `Boolean (null)` then first condition will fail and second condition will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of that code will stop if the first part (before the `&&`) evaluates as false, as you can see by testing the following code...

```
(false)&&(console.log("statement is true"));
```

and

```
(true)&&(console.log("statement is true"));
```

It's basically shorthand for an if statement, and I'd recommend against using it for the sake of you in the future, and anyone else who has to read your code.  While it's not the most complicated thing in the world, it's certainly less readable and more easily misread than a simple if statement.

Comment: yeah you're right, i wouldn't write code like that by myself.

Comment: There are much worse things you could do - this one doesn't really irk me personally, but I know it would throw some people.